# Is it possible to write these SELECT statements in a better way

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three `SELECT` statements in a MySQL Database.
I am currently migrate all queries to Oracle SQL, and I found one problem and I can not figure out how to fix it. I have this situation:

**Select statement 1**

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM order_items';
```

**Select statement 2**

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM order_acceptance_comments WHERE order_item_id = '.$out['ItemsID'];
```

**Select statement 3**

```
$sql = 'SELECT o.*, (SELECT name FROM projects WHERE ProjectID = o.ProjectID) as Name FROM orders o order by OrderID desc';
```

In one function I have three `select` statements. This seems inefficient, and I am looking for some advice or instruction on how to combine these three statements into one.

I did try to using `INNER JOIN` but I get error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error at Line: 29 Column: 8
```

Here is my code which I create:

```
 SELECT o.*, 
       (SELECT name FROM projects WHERE ProjectID = o.ProjectID) as Name 
       FROM orders o order by OrderID desc
       INNER JOIN order_items oi ON oi.ORDERID = o.ORDERID
       INNER JOIN order_acceptance_comments oac ON oac.ORDER_ID = o.ORDERID
       WHERE  order_item_id = 1
```

Here is the table's structure:

**Orders**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Order Items**

[image]

**Order Acceptance Comments**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply

```
select o.*, 
       p.name
from orders o join projects p on p.projectid = o.projectid
join order_items oi on oi.orderid = o.orderid
join order_acceptance_comments oac on oac.order_id = o.orderid
where order_item_id = 1                                          --> missing table alias
order by o.orderid desc
```

Note that `WHERE` clause's `order_item_id` lacks in table alias; it might, or might not be an error (depending on whether one or more tables contain that column). Anyway, I suggest you add it.

Comment: Thank you brother, I see that I miss table alias. My query is same as your but I miss table alias. :) 
Now it's working perfect !